# Анимация при наведении css3

Tags: css, css3

Верстаю psd-шку,дошел вот до определенного блока,вот что нужно сделать:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При наведении на контейнер в котором храниться цена ($0 и $19) нужно чтобы с низу выезжала эта желтая надпись(реализовал при помощи `position`,по умолчанию она `bottom: -35px` относительно контейнера с ценой,при наведении `bottom: 0`),и чтобы блок становился выше,обычная смена высоты приводит к тому,что блок растет в низ.

Вот код,будет слегка кривовато т.к стили я скинул только для айтемов,сорре

html:

```html
<div class="pricing__item">
                    <div class="price__title opensans-b">Professional</div>
                    <div class="price__sal">
                        <p><span>$</span>19</p>
                        <p class="opensans-r">Monthly Payment</p>
                        <div class="price__slider opensans-b">Our most popular</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="price__option">
                        <p class="opensans-r">5gb of space</p>
                        <p class="opensans-r">50gb of bandwidth</p>
                        <p class="opensans-r">12 websites</p>
                        <p class="opensans-r">Advenced customization</p>
                        <p class="opensans-r">wordpress integration</p>
                        <p class="opensans-r">email support</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

css:

```css
.pricing__item{
    width: 30%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.price__title{
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    color: #fff;
    background: #333;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
}

.price__sal{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;

    color: #fff;
    font-family: "Raleway",sans-sefir;
    font-size: 94px;
    font-weight: 700;
    background: #333;

    transition: all .2s;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.price__sal:hover .price__slider{
    transform: translateY(0px);
}

.price__sal span{
    font-size: 35px;
}

.price__sal p:first-child{
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.price__sal p:nth-child(2){
    margin-bottom: 20px;

    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 600;
    opacity: .5;
}

.price__slider{
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    transform: translateY(35px);

    background: #ff8b38;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;

    transition: all .2s;

}

.price__option{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.price__option p{
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
}
```

Comment: А если изначально делать темное и оранжевое как один целый блок, который будет под белым слоем? А при наведении делать `transform: translateY(-20px);` ?

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME глянь код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут вообще куча вариантов как всё это сделать, вот один из:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div {
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
  position: relative;
}

header {
  background-color: #212121;
  height: 30%;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

header:hover {
  transform: translateY(-30%);
}

h3 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 32%;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 2.5%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
  
  
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
  background-color: #FF6F00;
}

ul {
  height: 70%;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <header></header>
   <h3>Our most popular</h3>
   <ul></ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.list{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: auto;
  width: 60%;
  border: 20px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
  padding-left: 0;
}
.list li:nth-child(1){
  text-transform: capitalize;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 15px 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.list li:nth-child(2){
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 4px solid orange;
  padding-top: 15px 0;
  position: relative;
}

.list li:nth-child(2) > div{
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color:orange;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  display: none;
}
.list li:hover div{
  display: block;
}
.list li span{
    font-size: 30px;
    position: relative;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.list .dollar:after{
  content: 'O';
  font-size: 60px;
}

.list li span + span{
  display: block;
  color: grey;
  font-style: italic;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.list li:nth-child(2) ~ li{
  color: grey;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.list li:nth-child(3) ~ li:last-child{
   border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>basic</li>
  <li>
   <span class='dollar'>$</span>
   <span>free for life</span>
     <div class="block">
       our most popular
     </div>
  </li>
  <li> 1 gb of space</li>
  <li>10 gb of bandwidth</li>
  <li>3websites</li>
  <li>basic customization</li>
  <li>wordpress integration</li>
  <li>email support</li>  
</ul>
```

Comment: Так оно же увеличивается в низ :/

Comment: А надо вверх,я же написал "чтобы блок становился выше,обычная смена высоты приводит к тому,что блок растет в низ." Надо как на картинке